# Prevent Dialog from closing when locking the phone

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have an Android application where I create a dialog. If I lock the phone and unlock it the dialog is gone probably because I have paused the activity. Is there a way i can keep the dialog open after I unlock the phone or unpause the previously paused activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use a `DialogFragment` instead of a simple `Dialog`. Some details [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html) and the internet is full of DialogFragments :)